# I need to maven update after each eclipse change

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I've got a huge web project in eclipse using maven. After each change in any of Java classes in my daos or services or controllers when I restart tomcat the change doesn't get picked up. So I need to do maven update--restart tomcat or clean--maven install--restart tomcat to get the change picked on the next server restart. So, in other words, tomcat doesn't pick any changes on a restart. I know there might be 100 reasons for this but could anyone please share some likely causes since the productivity is quite low if I have to make maven install each time for a change to be picked? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, `mvn clean install` and then tomcat restart is quite common pattern for application deployment. In theory you can speed it up a little bit with things like JRebel.

In practice most people are quite happy with some build configuration inside their favourite IDE, which will make all these build/deploy things with one button click.

Comment: the thing is that usually you only need to restart the tomcat server rather than cleaning + maven install + tomcat restart..